# Why is config for my view going to config/local?

Tags: 8

We use config_split to slice off parts of the site config to other config folders (local, dev, stage, etc). This more or less works as expected.

I have one view which always exports to config/local even though there is nothing I can see in the config_split configuration which is suggesting it do this.

Any ideas why it fails to export to the correct folder (config/sync)?

Answer (score 2):

As is usually the case, 30 min after posting I figure it out.

My issue was caused by the "Include dependent configuration" option being enabled for the split configuration.